# Ubuntu 16.04 installed in UEFI mode and GPT partition. But windows 10 usb won't load in UEFI mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

So till yesterday I had an dual boot Ubuntu 16.04/Windows 10 Pro on my Asus R558U laptop. The Windows 10 Pro license was not mine, it was my friends, so I right click partitioned the drive.

I got a Windows 10 home USB from Microsoft [The USB is from microsoft, so can't change File system etc in the USB]. I plugged in the USB and tried to boot, but it boots only if CSM is enabled. During installation of Windows 10 it threw the error "Can't install, File is in GPT" or something similar [don't remember the exact words].

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to boot the Windows 10 usb in UEFI mode?
2. If no, please help me install Windows 10 in such a way that I don't lose my data.

Here is the output of `fdisk -l /sda`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A4FCFB45-757F-4715-A18A-F8E8AB9C520B

Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type 
/dev/sda1        2048  564168063 564166016   269G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda2   564170752  565092351    921600   450M Windows recovery    environment
/dev/sda3   565092352  565297151    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda4   565297152  565329919     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda5   565329920  771143679 205813760  98.1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6   771143680 1161213951 390070272   186G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda7  1161213952 1562443775 401229824 191.3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda8  1562443776 1953521663 391077888 186.5G Microsoft basic data
```

Any help is truly appreciated.

P.S. I know there are many similar questions, but they didn't solve my problem, hence asking a new one.

Comment: There may be Ubuntu-related ways around your problem, so I'm not voting to close your question; however, it's most likely that any solution you find will be Windows-specific, so I recommend you ask on a Windows forum. Finding a way to boot a Windows installation medium in EFI mode vs. BIOS mode, in particular, depends on Windows and/or your firmware, not on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a good Windows 10 iso file, you can create a USB boot drive for Windows, that can boot both in UEFI and BIOS mode. You can do it from current versions of Ubuntu with **mkusb-nox** with a text user interface or the new **mkusb version 12** alias **dus** with a graphical user interface. Maybe it is easiest from a persistent live Ubuntu system, which itself can boot from both BIOS mode and UEFI mode.

Install mkusb-nox from the stable PPA `ppa:mkusb/ppa` and version 12 alias dus from the unstable PPA `ppa:mkusb/unstable` according to the following links,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[mkusb/v7#Making_a_USB_drive_to_install_Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/v7#Making_a_USB_drive_to_install_Windows)

[mkusb/gui](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui)

[mkUSB-quick-start-manual-12.pdf](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=mkUSB-quick-start-manual-12.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't have an iso file. I got an USB from Microsoft.

Comment: I think that means that you have to install Windows in BIOS mode and install Ubuntu in the same mode afterwards. You had better copy all important data (documents, pictures, video clips etc and maybe also downloaded programs and license keys) to another drive, for example a USB hard disk drive. Or you can keep the current drive (seen as /dev/sda in your question) and install Windows 10 into another (new) drive. - I see no linux partition, did you overwrite Ubuntu when you installed from your friend's install drive?

Comment: No. /dev/sda1/ is my linux partition. I have no idea why it is showing Microsoft basic data. I have already backed up my stuff. Thinking about reinstalling . Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, I think it is a good idea to reinstall. If you have a lot of tweaks, it might be a good idea to copy /home to a separate partition and keep it, when reinstalling Ubuntu. You can also set up a *data* partition with the NTFS file system, to be used from Ubuntu as well as from Windows.